# Amazon ec2 server timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2, timeout

I know this question has been asked many times before, but in my case none of the answers seem to solve the question. I have followed all of amazon's trouble shooting guide, but I'm still unable to connect to my amazon instance. Any suggestions what else I can do are appreciated.

I would love to put the screenshots but stack exchange's excessive policing doesn't allow me to do anything until I get 10 reputation points. If you give me one or two upvotes I can post the the rest of the details needed.

thanks

[image: Timeout]

[Instance][2]

[Security group allowing access from everywhere][3]

[Subnet][4]

[Routing table][5]

[Internet gateway][6]

[Network acl][7]

Comment: Your problem with "excessive policing" would be easily solved by copying/pasting your terminal sessions into proper code blocks instead of using screenshots, which are sub-optimal in nearly every way.

Comment: What about the screenshots of amazon ec2?

Comment: I embedded one of your images, but the other links seem to be broken.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm only allowed to post one link.

Answer (score 0):

Your bind address appears to be incorrect, or at least different from how I connect using putty. Try using this

```
ec2-user@52.90.70.133
```

You can also connect from the EC2 instance page of your AWS console.

I have a bit more about this on one of my [aws tutorials](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/), you may benefit from reading it.

Comment: The browser console doesn't work either

Comment: @Nicolas The browser console uses SSH, so that's expected.

Comment: So then the problem must be somewhere with Amazon

Comment: Post your security group setup in your question, as text. Be precise, and lay it out properly in a way that's easy to understand. If you have an ACL post that. Also check your computer and local network firewall. This will be user error, it's just tracking down which error you made. Can you connect using HTTP on port 80, assuming you have a web server running? Worth checking - sudo yum install nginx